# HTML link to user's email with form? like craigslist "reply"

Tags: html, forms

I'm working on a small project for my personal website. I've looked around Stack Overflow and Google and haven't found many answers.

My goal: I'm  trying to take an image and make it a hyperlink to open a user's default email client on their smartphone or PC. Just like, the Craigslist "reply" button directs you to your personal email client with the destination and subject already pre-filled out.

[image: Example Image]

Is this something I could do using strictly using HTML?

Any code or links are greatly appreciated.

Comment: most of it use `API` to redirect to your email. Just like [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/) for gmail only. If you need to support several email service then you need to use each `API` for different email service provider

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have even tried anything but it's very simple:

User's email is: `test@example.com`.

```
<a href="mailto:test@example.com">Reply</a>
```

---

You can also make the user's email dynamic. Here's an example using PHP:

```
$email = // get the user's email in the database or whatever you want

<a href="<?php echo $email; ?>">Reply</a>
```

---

You can also set the email subject and/or body when they click that link. Here's an example with the email subject and body set:

```
<a href="mailto:test@example.com?subject=Message Subject&body=Hi, this is just the body of the email.">Reply</a>
```

Comment: I've tried that before, but It doesn't work for me. I'd like to have the client click on the hyperlinked image and bring the user to their email address with the information pre-filled. Like a re-direct?

Comment: @JohnSmith1999 What do you mean by "bring the user to their email address with the information pre-filled. Like a redirect?"? Also, you can hyperlink an image by replacing "Reply" with `<img src="your image url">`

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way to do this... just make a hyperlink with this information and it works perfectly...

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm&fs=1&to=[ENTER DESTINATION EMAIL HERE]&su=[ENTER SUBJECT HERE]&body=%0A%0A[ENTER BODY MESSAGE HERE]%0A&tf=1